# AWS EC2 Nodejs | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in vuejs project

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

**I am running a nodejs app on AWS ec2 instance(t2.small). After it works around one week. Below out of memory error comes.** Searched for same issues, found there is a workaround to increase "--max-old-space-size" option. However, my question is

1. if i set --max-old-space-size = 4096(4gb). Do i need to update the aws instance to get more memory(as small type only have 2 gb memory)
2. This max-old-space-size setting,finally will it also hit memory limitation? At the beginning, the app is working fine, but after period of time, app is crushed.  If that, how to slove this issue effectively?

**The full error message as below:**

<--- Last few GCs --->

[30600:0x5007800] 429029005 ms: Mark-sweep 977.8 (1007.7) -> 970.6 (1008.9) MB, 2379.3 / 0.5 ms  (average mu = 0.220, current mu = 0.190) allocation failure scavenge might n
ot succeed
[30600:0x5007800] 429031937 ms: Mark-sweep 979.0 (1008.9) -> 971.8 (1010.4) MB, 2396.6 / 0.4 ms  (average mu = 0.202, current mu = 0.183) allocation failure scavenge might n
ot succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0xa02ec0 node::Abort() [node]
2: 0x94e471 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
3: 0xb765de v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
4: 0xb76957 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
5: 0xd311f5  [node]
6: 0xd31d7f  [node]
7: 0xd3fe0b v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
8: 0xd439cc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [no
de]
9: 0xd120ab v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
10: 0x105802f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x13fdfd9  [node]
./backend.sh: line 6: 30600 Aborted                 node server.js

Thanks for all your help!